# Bind to Parent Property throught a RelativeSource

Tags: silverlight, binding

I can not figure out whats is wrong.
I wish to bind the DropShadowEffect's color to the TextBox Foreground color. When I bind using  the ElementName bind property it works fine, but I need to use the RelativeSource (looking for the first TextBox object in the VisualThree).

Below is my code (it's Silverlight 5):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Foreground="Blue" MinWidth="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect x:Name="ShadowEffect" BlurRadius="60" Direction="345" ShadowDepth="50" Color="{Binding Path=Foreground.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}}"></DropShadowEffect>
    </TextBox.Effect>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

U should use {RelativeSource self}, because your effect property relies on the TextBox("TextBox1"), not on the TextBox parents.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Foreground="Blue" MinWidth="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"> 
<TextBox.Effect> 
    <DropShadowEffect x:Name="ShadowEffect" BlurRadius="60" Direction="345" ShadowDepth="50" Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=Foreground.Color}"></DropShadowEffect> 
</TextBox.Effect>
```

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=d1b83ace5eb2c92a#cid=D1B83ACE5EB2C92A&id=D1B83ACE5EB2C92A%21167

Comment: Dima, I saw your image. If the textbox foreground color is setted to Blue the shadow should be blue too if the bind was working fine.